# forwarding x11 by SSH.NET c# library

Tags: ssh.net, x11-forwarding, teststand

I am using the ssh.net as an extension in TestStand, but I need somehow display the x11 forwarding. Is it possible somehow?
I am using xming server on my win. machine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
 SSHInstance = new SshClient(HostOrIP, Port, Username, Password);
 SSHInstance.Connect();
 streamSSH = SSHInstance.CreateShellStream(ShellID, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2000000);

 ForwardedPortRemote forwardedPortRemote = new ForwardedPortRemote(6000 +X11ServerDisplay, HostOrIP, 6000 + X11LocalDisplay);
 SSHInstance.AddForwardedPort(forwardedPortRemote);
 forwardedPortRemote.Start();
```